# Search on a webpage using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to fetch the html contents of a webpage. I am not sure how to define the search field,
I tried the following.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests


ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)
header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome)}
print(header)
body = {'Search': '1.1.1.1'}
url = "https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/Default.aspx"
htmlContent = requests.get(url, data=body) 
print(htmlContent.text)
```

Could someone suggest how to define the right search field?

Comment: The search looks to be event driven in java script / ajax style update to the page so you will need to use something that can handle JS events like selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily done with selenium like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

search_input = '1.1.1.1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/Default.aspx')
driver.find_element_by_id('MainBody_txtSrchAutoFill').send_keys(search_input)
driver.find_element_by_id('MainBody_ImgSrch').click()
result_table = driver.find_element_by_id('MainBody_gvSearch')
print(result_table.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get the following error while setting the path for chrome executable,` "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0"`

Comment: Download a webdriver from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads