# Accessing the contents on links provided on a webpage while webscraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is a followup question of my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216826/search-on-a-webpage-using-python-requests/58217060?noredirect=1#comment102811076_58217060) question.
I am trying to access the contents of a [webpage](https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/).

I could search for contents on the webpage. However, I am not sure how to access the contents in links given on the webpage.

For instance, the first line of the search result for id  `1.1.1.1` is 
`36EUL/ADL_7 1.1.1.1 spectrophotometry .... C ...`.

The secondary id `36EUL/ADL_7`, in the first line, has another link that opens when clicked.

I am not sure how to access the contents of the search result of the secondary id.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

The solution posted by Sers works for `search_term = 1.1.1.1` with the following output format( same as the obtained output)

```
EC Number: 1.1.1.1, Reference Id: 36EUL/ADL_7, Evaluation: C
T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.4, K': 1.3E-5
T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.0, K': 5.3E-5
T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.7, K': 1.3E-4
```

However, for a different search term, i.e. `search_term = 2.7.2.3`

Output obtained: (fails because the output table in the database has 4 columns excluding reference id)

```
EC Number: 2.7.2.3, Reference Id: 95SCH/TRA_581, Evaluation: C
T(K): 277.15, pH: 7.5, K': ethylene glycol, 40 %
T(K): 277.15, pH: 7.5, K': none
```

Expected output:

```
EC Number: 2.7.2.3, Reference Id: 95SCH/TRA_581, Evaluation: C
T(K): 277.15, pH: 7.5, cosolvent: ethylene glycol, 40 %, K':8.0E-5
T(K): 277.15, pH: 7.5, cosolvent: none, K':1.5E-4
```

lines 85-87 , isn't the correct assignment always.

```
tk_list = page.select("#MainBody_extraData td:nth-child(1)")
ph_list = page.select("#MainBody_extraData td:nth-child(2)")
k_list = page.select("#MainBody_extraData td:nth-child(3)")
```

My suggestion is ,

Can we map the column name and the corresponding values while parsing the values from columns?

```
<table bgcolor="White" bordercolor="White" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" id="MainBody_extraData" width="100%">
<tr bgcolor="#4A3C8C">
<th scope="col"><font color="#E7E7FF"><b>T(K)</b></font></th><th scope="col"><font color="#E7E7FF"><b>pH </b></font></th><th scope="col"><font color="#E7E7FF"><b>cosolvent </b></font></th><th scope="col"><font color="#E7E7FF"><b>K' </b></font></th><th scope="col"><font color="#E7E7FF"><b>95SCH/TRA_581</b></font></th>
</tr><tr bgcolor="#DEDFDE">
<td><font color="Black">277.15</font></td><td><font color="Black">7.5</font></td><td><font color="Black">ethylene glycol, 40 %</font></td><td><font color="Black">8.0E-5</font></td><td><font color="Black">95SCH/TRA_581</font></td>
</tr><tr bgcolor="White">
<td><font color="Black">277.15</font></td><td><font color="Black">7.5</font></td><td><font color="Black">none</font></td><td><font color="Black">1.5E-4</font></td><td><font color="Black">95SCH/TRA_581</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you want? the contents of the page after the click? Or just the contents of the table?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Many thanks for the response. The contents of the table displayed after clicking the secondary id. In short, the output posted by Sers is the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All can be done using **Requests** and **BeautifulSoup** without Selenium. 
Here code how to get data with details:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://randr.nist.gov'
ec_name = 'enzyme'
search_term = '1.1.1.1'

url = f'{base_url}/{ec_name}/'

with requests.Session() as session:
    # get __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION parameters to use them in POST parameters
    response = session.get(url)
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    view_state = page.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    view_state_generator = page.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    event_validation = page.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]

    data = {
        '__EVENTTARGET': '',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__LASTFOCUS': '',
        '__VIEWSTATE': view_state,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': view_state_generator,
        '__SCROLLPOSITIONX': '0',
        '__SCROLLPOSITIONY': '0',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': event_validation,
        'ctl00$MainBody$txtSrchAutoFill': search_term,
        'ctl00$MainBody$repoList': 'Enzyme_thermo',
        'ctl00$MainBody$ImgSrch.x': '0',
        'ctl00$MainBody$ImgSrch.y': '0'
    }
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # get all rows
    rows = page.select("#MainBody_gvSearch tr")
    # first row is header, remove it
    rows.remove(rows[0])

    for row in rows:
        reference_id = row.select_one("[id*='lbSearch']").text.strip()
        ec_number = row.select_one("[id*='lblECNumber']").text.strip()
        method = row.select_one("[id*='lblMethod']").text.strip()
        buffer = row.select_one("[id*='lblBuffer']").text.strip()
        reaction = row.select_one("[id*='lblReaction']").text.strip()
        enzyme = row.select_one("[id*='lblEnzyme']").text.strip()
        cofactor = row.select_one("[id*='lblCofactor']").text.strip()
        evaluation = row.select_one("[id*='lblEvaluation']").text.strip()

        print(f"EC Number: {ec_number}, Reference Id: {reference_id}, Evaluation: {evaluation}")

        # get details
        params = (
            ('ID', reference_id),
            ('finalterm', search_term),
            ('data', ec_name),
        )
        response = session.get('https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx', params=params)
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        # parse general information
        if page.find("span", text='Reference:'):
            reference = page.find("span", text='Reference:').find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()
        if page.find("span", text='pH:'):
            ph = page.find("span", text='pH:').find_parent("td").find_next_sibling("td").text.strip()

        # parse table
        extra_data = []
        try:
            table_headers = [x.text.strip() for x in page.select("#MainBody_extraData th")]
            table_data = [x.text.strip() for x in page.select("#MainBody_extraData td")]

            headers_count = len(table_headers)
            for i in range(0, len(table_data), headers_count):
                row = {}
                row_data = table_data[i:i + headers_count]
                for column_index, h in enumerate(table_headers):
                    row[h] = row_data[column_index]

                print("T(K): {}, pH: {}, K': {}".format(row["T(K)"], row["pH"], row["K'"]))
                extra_data.append(row)

        except Exception as ex:
            print("No details table found")
            print(ex)

        print("")
```

Output of some values:

> EC Number:  1.1.1.1, Reference Id: 36EUL/ADL_7, Evaluation: C
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.4, K': 1.3E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.0, K': 5.3E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.7, K': 1.3E-4
>   
>   EC Number:  1.1.1.1, Reference Id: 37ADL/SRE_8, Evaluation: D
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.05, K': 6.0E-6
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.25, K': 7.7E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 8.0, K': 1.2E-5
>   
>   EC Number:  1.1.1.1, Reference Id: 37NEG/WUL_9, Evaluation: C
>   T(K): 293.15, pH: 7.9, K': 7.41E-4
>   
>   EC Number:  1.1.1.1, Reference Id: 38SCH/HEL_10, Evaluation: C
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.30, K': 2.6E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.85, K': 8.8E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.15, K': 1.9E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.34, K': 3.0E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.61, K': 5.1E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.77, K': 8.0E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 8.17, K': 2.2E-3
>   
>   EC Number:  1.1.1.1, Reference Id: 38SCH/HEL_23, Evaluation: C
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.39, K': 9.1E-6
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.60, K': 3.0E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 6.85, K': 5.1E-5
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.18, K': 1.5E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.31, K': 2.3E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 7.69, K': 5.6E-4
>   T(K): 298.15, pH: 8.06, K': 1.1E-3

Comment: @Natasha did the answer helped?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. That was of great help. However, there is a problem while trying to use `page.select("#MainBody_extraData td:nth-child(3)")` in line 85-87 of the code for other search terms like '2.7.2.3'. There are more than 3 child,  T(K) pH cosolvent and K' -4 tags are present. Whereas, with the search term in the question --T(K) pH and K' - 3 tags were present. Therefore, it would be nice to look for the   tag name and assign the value to appropriate tag name. PS: Somehow, the accept answer option isn't working

Comment: Could you please check the edit? I have added an example to explain my question

Comment: I noticed there is an additional field `Reference` , in the webpage[for example](https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/DataDetails.aspx?ID=56TAL/MAR_166&finalterm=1.1.1.50&data=enzyme) . i.e before the line `reference_id = row.select_one("[id*='lbSearch']").text.strip()`. However, I am not able to find it the output of print(row). Should I look for this information elsewhere? Additionally, is it possible to retrive the 2 hyperlinks saved in the line below `evaluation = row.select_one("[id*='lblEvaluation']").text.strip()` in the variable `row`?

Comment: You can get reference using `reference = row.select_one("[id*='lbTitle']").text.strip()`

Comment: I tried `data_dict['reference'] = row.select_one("[id*='lbTitle']").text.strip()`,         I get the following error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.` When the variable `row` is printed I couldn't find the title information stored in it

Answer (score 1):

I presume you would like to click on each link on table and then grab the content of the details after navigate to the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
search_input = '1.1.1.1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('path of the chrome driver')
driver.get('https://randr.nist.gov/enzyme/Default.aspx')
driver.find_element_by_id('MainBody_txtSrchAutoFill').send_keys(search_input)
driver.find_element_by_id('MainBody_ImgSrch').click()
links=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='MainBody_gvSearch']//tr/td[1]/a")))
for link in range(len(links)):
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MainBody_gvSearch']//tr/td[1]/a")))
    print("################################")
    print(links[link].text)
    print("################################")
    links[link].click()
    try :
        itemrows=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='MainBody_DataList1']//table//tr")))
        for row in itemrows:
           print(row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text + " " + row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text )



    except:
        print(driver.find_element_by_id("MainBody_lblErrorDetails").text)


    driver.back()
```

**Output on console:**

```
################################
36EUL/ADL_7
################################
Reference: von Euler, H.; Adler, E.; Hellstrvm, H.; Hoppe-Seyler's Z. Physiol. Chem.; 241, 239 (1936).
Reference ID: 36EUL/ADL_7
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: phosphate
pH: 6.4 - 7.7
Evaluation: C
################################
37ADL/SRE_8
################################
Reference: Adler, E.; Sreenivasaya, M.; Hoppe-Seyler's Z. Physiol. Chem.; 249, 24 (1937).
Reference ID: 37ADL/SRE_8
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: 
pH: 6.05 - 8.0
Evaluation: D
################################
37NEG/WUL_9
################################
Reference: Negelein, E.; Wulff, H.-J.; Biochem. Z.; 293, 351 (1937).
Reference ID: 37NEG/WUL_9
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: phosphate
pH: 7.9
Evaluation: C
################################
38SCH/HEL_10
################################
Reference: Schlenk, F.; Hellstrvm, H.; von Euler, H.; Ber. Dtsch. Chem. Ges.; 71, 1471 (1938).
Reference ID: 38SCH/HEL_10
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: 
pH: 6.30 - 8.17
Evaluation: C
################################
38SCH/HEL_23
################################
Reference: Schlenk, F.; Hellstrvm, H.; von Euler, H.; Ber. Dtsch. Chem. Ges.; 71, 1471 (1938).
Reference ID: 38SCH/HEL_23
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: 
pH: 6.39 - 8.06
Evaluation: C
################################
50RAC_11
################################
Reference: Racker, E.; J. Biol. Chem.; 184, 313 (1950).
Reference ID: 50RAC_11
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: pyrophosphate (0.01 mol dm-3)
pH: 7.4 - 9.5
Evaluation: B
################################
51BLA_65
################################
Reference: Blakley, R.L.; Biochem. J.; 49, 257 (1951).
Reference ID: 51BLA_65
EC Value: 1.1.1.14 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry and chemical analysis
Buffer: potassium phosphate (0.03 mol dm-3)
pH: 8.0
Evaluation: B
################################
51BLI_35
################################
Reference: Bliss, A.F.; Arch. Biochem. Biophys.; 31, 197 (1951).
Reference ID: 51BLI_35
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: sodium pyrophosphate (0.015 mol dm-3)
pH: 6.6 - 9.5
Evaluation: C
################################
51THE/BON_12
################################
Reference: Theorell, H.; Bonnichsen, R.; Acta Chem. Scand.; 5, 1105 (1951).
Reference ID: 51THE/BON_12
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: phosphate (0.05 mol dm-3) and {glycine (0.10 mol dm-3)+ NaOH}
pH: 7.0 - 10.0
Evaluation: B
################################
52BUR_29
################################
Reference: Burton, K.; Biochim. Biophys. Acta; 8, 114 (1952).
Reference ID: 52BUR_29
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: 
Buffer: 
pH: 
Evaluation: B
################################
53BUR/WIL_30
################################
Reference: Burton, K.; Wilson, T.H.; Biochem. J.; 54, 86 (1953).
Reference ID: 53BUR/WIL_30
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: pyrophosphate (0.0055 mol dm-3)
pH: 7.03 - 8.83
Evaluation: A
################################
54WIL/BAN_66
################################
Reference: Williams-Ashman, H.G.; Banks, J.; Arch. Biochem. Biophys.; 50, 513 (1954).
Reference ID: 54WIL/BAN_66
EC Value: 1.1.1.14 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: 
pH: 
Evaluation: C
################################
55WOL/KAP_75
################################
Reference: Wolff, J.B.; Kaplan, N.O.; Methods Enzymol.; 1, 346 (1955).
Reference ID: 55WOL/KAP_75
EC Value: 1.1.1.17 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: phosphate (0.1 mol dm-3) or bicarbonate (0.1 mol dm-3)
pH: 7.0
Evaluation: C
################################
56KAP/CIO_13
################################
Reference: Kaplan, N.O.; Ciotti, M.M.; Stolzenbach, F.E.; J. Biol. Chem.; 221, 833 (1956).
Reference ID: 56KAP/CIO_13
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: phosphate (0.1 mol dm-3)
pH: 6.51 - 8.07
Evaluation: C
################################
56KAP/CIO_22
################################
Reference: Kaplan, N.O.; Ciotti, M.M.; Stolzenbach, F.E.; J. Biol. Chem.; 221, 833 (1956).
Reference ID: 56KAP/CIO_22
EC Value: 1.1.1.1 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: phosphate (0.1 mol dm-3)
pH: 6.51 - 8.07
Evaluation: C
################################
56LAR/JAC_77
################################
Reference: Larner, J.; Jackson, W.T.; Graves, D.J.; Stamer, J.R.; Arch. Biochem. Biophys.; 60, 352 (1956).
Reference ID: 56LAR/JAC_77
EC Value: 1.1.1.18 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: pyrophosphate (0.01 mol dm-3)
pH: 8.10 - 8.92
Evaluation: B
################################
56WOL/KAP_76
################################
Reference: Wolff, J.B.; Kaplan, N.O.; J. Biol. Chem.; 218, 849 (1956).
Reference ID: 56WOL/KAP_76
EC Value: 1.1.1.17 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: chemical analysis and spectrophotometry
Buffer: 
pH: 6 - 10
Evaluation: C
################################
57HOL/TOU_56
################################
Reference: Hollmann, S.; Touster, O.; J. Biol. Chem.; 225, 87 (1957).
Reference ID: 57HOL/TOU_56
EC Value: 1.1.1.10 (ENZYME | KEGG)
Method: spectrophotometry
Buffer: Tris (0.05 mol dm-3)
pH: 6.95 - 8.70
Evaluation: B
so on.......................
```