# Issue while scraping the contents of a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a follow up to my question posted here
[Accessing the contents on links provided on a webpage while webscraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269851/accessing-the-contents-on-links-provided-on-a-webpage-while-webscraping)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://randr.nist.gov'
ec_name = 'enzyme'
search_term = '1.1.1.1'

url = f'{base_url}/{ec_name}/'

with requests.Session() as session:
    # get __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION parameters to use them in POST parameters
    response = session.get(url)
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    view_state = page.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
    view_state_generator = page.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")["value"]
    event_validation = page.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]

    data = {
        '__EVENTTARGET': '',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__LASTFOCUS': '',
        '__VIEWSTATE': view_state,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': view_state_generator,
        '__SCROLLPOSITIONX': '0',
        '__SCROLLPOSITIONY': '0',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': event_validation,
        'ctl00$MainBody$txtSrchAutoFill': search_term,
        'ctl00$MainBody$repoList': 'Enzyme_thermo',
        'ctl00$MainBody$ImgSrch.x': '0',
        'ctl00$MainBody$ImgSrch.y': '0'
    }
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # get all rows
    rows = page.select("#MainBody_gvSearch tr")
    # first row is header, remove it
    rows.remove(rows[0])

    for row in rows:
        ec_number = row.select_one("[id*='lblECNumber']").text.strip()
        print(ec_number)
```

Output:

```
2.7.1.24
2.7.1.23
```

The search key is `2.7.1.2`

```
search_term = '2.7.1.2'
```

But the results returned are 2.7.1.24, 2.7.1.23 since the search string is partially contained in them. Instead, I expect the search to return none when there are no hits for the exact user-defined search.

Suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The website's search itself returns partial matches as results - if you search the site directly for `1.1.1.1`, it still returns `1.1.1.153` and similar. It might be possible to force it into exact searches, but it also might not be, and it's probably more effort than it's worth.

The best solution is probably to filter the pages after you get them back, only keeping the ones that are exact matches.

In the final section of your example code, you can replace the last three lines with this to only display the right numbers:

```py
for row in rows:
    ec_number = row.select_one("[id*='lblECNumber']").text.strip()
    if ec_number == search_term:
        print(ec_number)
```

With that working, you can then do whatever processing you need on the final results. I know that probably seems like a facile solution, but (unless there are other factors in play that I'm not aware of) there's nothing wrong with taking all the data it gives you and then filtering as a secondary stage.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing the same for now:)